# How to make value from button be displayed onto tkinter, when clicked rather than shell?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

I am basically wanting to click on a button and have the value go by the label, rather than the shell. I think the main issue is with me not declaring the label as a variable, but am not completely sure. If I was to guess, it is an issue with declaring it as a label, but I am sure that there is another way to have it to where, I can click on the button and the value gets displayed on tkinter, rather than the shell.

```
from tkinter import *


Value1 = 8.75
Value2 = 6.25
Value3 = int(7.00)

class BaseValue():
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk() # Creates a window
        window.title("Value Display")
        window.geometry('640x480')

        btValue2 = Button(window,  text = "Value 2", fg = "blue", command = self.Value2).place(
            x = 20, y = 20)
        btValue1 = Button(window, text = "Value 1", fg = "blue", command = self.Value1).place(
            x = 20, y = 60)
        btValue3 = Button (window, text = "Value 3", fg = "blue", command = self.Value3).place(
            x = 20, y = 100)
        Label(window, text = "Value: ", fg = "Green").place(
            x = 400, y = 100)

        window.mainloop() # Create an event loop

    def Value2(self):
        print("Value: ", Value2)

    def Value1(self):
        print("Value: ", Value1)

    def Value3(self):
        print("Value: ", Value3)

BaseValue() # Create an object to invoke __init__method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the text of the Label via the configure method like this:

```
from tkinter import *


Value1 = 8.75
Value2 = 6.25
Value3 = int(7.00)

class BasePrice():

    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk() # Creates a window
        window.title("Price Calculator")
        window.geometry('640x480')

        btValue2 = Button(window,  text = "Value 2", fg = "blue", command = self.Value2).place(
            x = 20, y = 20)
        btValue1 = Button(window, text = "Value 1", fg = "blue", command = self.Value1).place(
            x = 20, y = 60)
        btValue3 = Button (window, text = "Value 3", fg = "blue", command = self.Value3).place(
            x = 20, y = 100)
        self.temp = Label(window, text = "Value: ", fg = "Green")
        self.temp.place(x = 400, y = 100)
        window.mainloop() # Create an event loop

    def Value2(self):
        print("Price: ", Value2)
        self.temp.configure(text="Value: %s" % Value2)

    def Value1(self):
        print("Price: ", Value1)
        self.temp.configure(text="Value: %s" % Value1)

    def Value3(self):
        print("Price: ", Value3)
        self.temp.configure(text="Value: %s" % Value3)

BasePrice() # Create an object to invoke __init__method
```

To add multiple values you could do something like this:

```
old = self.temp.cget("text")
self.temp.configure(text="%s, %s" % (old, ValueX))
```

Comment: please mark this question as solved so other users can see that there is a solution for your question.

Comment: When using a class, there's no need for a global — e.g. make `temp` an instance attribute and reference it via `self.temp` in the other methods.

Comment: Follow up question, how would I make it towhere, multiple values are displayed? Would it need to be a loop?